# Android media codec config without surface window cause decoder more delay

Tags: android, delay, surfaceview, android-mediacodec

When I use Android mediacodec to decode video, I found a strangeness issue. If I config the [AMediaCodec_configure](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/media#group___media_1ga9055d95848e3db182d198f856a817324) without surface window. The decoder delay is increase like 4ms more or less. I use the [LiveVideo10ms](https://github.com/Consti10/LiveVideo10ms) opensource code for test. This app can show the decoder delay. If I set the **AMediaCodec_configure** surface window to nullptr, the delay will increase as the following image:
decoder with image show:
[image]
decoder without image show:
[image]

I have tried many devices and all device with the same result, without the **surface window** will cause more decoder delay.